# Calculate file size and block-filesize of all files in a directory

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

How do I calculate the block-filesize that all the files in a directory take?
and how do I calculate the real size of all the files in the directory?

I tried some variations with df/du but they don't seem to work.

Comment: What's wrong with `du -s the-dir`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -sa | awk '{ SUM += $1 } END { print "Block size=" SUM }'
```

the `-s` option of `ls`  print the allocated size of each file, in blocks

And the real size :

```
ls -la | awk '{ SUM += $5 } END { print "Dir size=" SUM }'
```

Comment: parsing the output of `ls` is a greatly inferior method to using `du`. Parsing `ls` is generally a bad idea: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls. `du` is specifically made for getting information about disk space usage/size on disk.